# CKEDITOR: Wrap text in a pre-defined div

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I got an edit page with an embedded ckeditor textarea.

To show in the preview how the inserted text will appear in the final page, I have already included the final page .css files (via CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss). But to fully get the final result I need also to automatically wrap in a div class the entire text inserted by the user.

Can this be done? (and +1: can this be done avoiding that the user can delete the div or write the text out of the div?)

Answer (score 0):

CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor1', 
{
bodyClass: 'yourDivClass'
}